# Material-UI Data-Grid: How pass parameter to custom toolbar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am defining a custom toolbar in datagrid (Material-UI) following (see: https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/rendering/#toolbar)
I started from this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/x58yv?file=/demo.js

I want to show or hide toolbar  with transition.
As we can't passing custom props to component:

```
   <DataGrid
    ...
    components={{ Toolbar: CustomToolbar }}
    ...
   </DataGrid>
```

So i have used context API like this:

```
   export function CustomToolbar(props: GridBaseComponentProps) {
    const classes = useToolbarStyles();
    const toolbarContext = useContext(ToolbarContext);
    return (
        <Collapse in={toolbarContext.toolbar}>
            <GridToolbarContainer className={classes.root}>
                <GridColumnsToolbarButton />
                <GridFilterToolbarButton />
                <GridDensitySelector />
                <GridToolbarExport />
            </GridToolbarContainer>
        </Collapse>
    );
   }
```

It works but is it any better solution ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be able to use the `componentsProps` prop of DataGrid to pass in any additional props (see https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/), ex.

```
<DataGrid
    ...
    components={{ Toolbar: CustomToolbar }}
    componentsProps={{ toolbar: { myCustomProp: 8 } }}
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot perfect and rapide anwser :) happy face !

Comment: Caveat: The typings for material-ui do not check prop types so you will need to enforce the types yourself.

Answer (score 5):

in MUI V6, it looks like this. I would have added a comment to Alex's answer but stupid stackoverflow idiotically won't let me comment.

```
<DataGrid
    ...
    slots={{ Toolbar: CustomToolbar }}
    slotProps={{ toolbar: { myCustomProp: 8 } }}
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

this also works

```
    <DataGrid
      autoHeight
      checkboxSelection
      columns={columns}
      rows={rowsSearched}
      loading={isLoading}
      disableColumnMenu
      paginationMode="server"
      slots={{
        toolbar:()=><CustomToolBar searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue} setFilterOpen={setFilterOpen}/>
      }}
      sx={{
        '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders':{
          backgroundColor:'primary.light'
        },            
        '.MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer': {
          visibility: 'visible',
        },
        '.MuiDataGrid-sortIcon': {
          opacity: 'inherit !important',
        },
      }}
```